# How to add all members of a community to a circle in Google?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

After joining a particular community I would like to follow all of its members (adding them to a dedicated circle for convenience). Can this be done any way easier than clicking and adding every one of them manually?

Comment: That's likely not an option because Circles are limited in size, but Communities really aren't.

Comment: That said, it doesn't look like there is a way, even for smaller communities.

Comment: There's a way! I saw it in a video that I'm trying to track down now...